# Spyder profiler refuses to profile a certain file

Tags: python, spyder, profiler

Each time I try to profile my code, it profiles the code as it was before I made the last few changes.

My program is just a bunch of functions, and one call of a test function at the very end. I was profiling test `function 1`, swapped the call at the end to call test `function 2`, but since then each time I profile it shows the profiling of the code that called `function 1`.

Here is the **output** of the profiler:

```
        [ WARN:0@1.960] global shadow_sift.hpp:13 SIFT_create DEPRECATED: cv.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() is deprecated due SIFT tranfer to the main repository. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16736
    QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x26c50a0) is not the object's thread (0x27b7580).
    Cannot move to target thread (0x26c50a0)
    
    qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/fdeleu/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
    This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
    
    Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl.
```

Just now I tried to profile a test file then go back to my file, but it wont go back to profiling the right file.

I tried saving, rebooting **spdyer**, clearing the *kernel*, pressing the little bin on the right of the profiler panel, profiling a different file and going back to the original one (broke it more).

I'm using a weird *linux* (I can't check the exact version), a *miniconda3 environment* with **python 3.10.10**, **spyder 5.4.3**, **conda 23.3.1**.

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer: https://github.com/NVlabs/instant-ngp/discussions/300#discussioncomment-3179213

I was using opencv-python, which came in packaged ith plugins that conflicted with existing packages in my environment. To get rid of these packages, I unsintalled opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python and installed opencv-python-headless and opencv-contrib-python-headless